# Python pandas read file, write to excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file like this :

```
SOME_INFO_BEGIN
....
....
SOME_INFO_END
ACTUAL_DETAIL_BEGIN
TEST|1|23|abcd|
TEST|2|5|efgs|
TEST|3|124|zyz|       
ACTUAL_DETAIL_END
```

I only to read the lines between ACTUAL_DETAILS_BEGIN and ACTUAL_DETAILS_END 
and they will always start with TEST, however i also only to read the line which has 5 in the 3rd column.

The below code works for me except it gets all the 3 lines -

```
with open(dir+filename, 'r') as filehandle:  
    filecontent = filehandle.readlines()
ifa = [k for k in filecontent if 'TEST' in k]
df = pd.DataFrame([sub.split("|") for sub in ifa])
df.columns= ['Type','Amt','Desc','Value1','Value2']
df1 = df[['Type','Desc']]
print(df1)
df1.to_excel (dir+"test.xlsx", index = False)
```

Q1. Is there a better way to code this ? For eg. how is the filehandle closed for excel write?

Q2. How do i only pick up the 2nd row ?

Comment: Why are you not opening the file in pandas directly?

Comment: Nevermind. You could use the csv module to open the file and parse the lines lazily. `readlines()` is putting the whole thing in memory before you even start filtering

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to test with but you can iterate files and lazily load the lines. Perhaps this is more efficient:

```
rebuilt = []

with open(dir+filename, 'r') as infile:
    for row in infile:
        if row[:4] == 'TEST':
            rebuild.append(row.split('|'))

df = pd.DataFrame(rebuilt, columns= ['Type','Amt','Desc','Value1','Value2'])
```

`readlines()` is going to load the whole thing into memory, regardless, so you can filter the lines as you read them instead. You're also splitting each line before checking a condition, so it may be faster to check against a list slice.